# DISTINCT values of string_agg in window function in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get `string_agg` to show me only distinct values for a particular column, the column is called `it_org_6` and it is the only column in this involved query that needs to output the unique strings. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how can i achieve this while still preserving the rest of the query without huge modifications.

```
with numeric_encoding_groups as (
    select
        numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version,
        'Y' as binary_check
    from
        evergreen t
        join(
            select
                install_path,
                row_number() over (
                    order by
                        install_path
                ) as numeric_encoding
            from
                (
                    select
                        distinct install_path
                    from
                        evergreen
                ) encoded_install_path
        ) c on t.install_path = c.install_path
    group by
        numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version
    having
        count(distinct t.it_service) > 1
),
numeric_encondings_all AS (
    select
        t.*,
        numeric_encoding
    from
        evergreen t
        join(
            select
                install_path,
                row_number() over (
                    order by
                        install_path
                ) as numeric_encoding
            from
                (
                    select
                        distinct install_path
                    from
                        evergreen
                ) encoded_install_path
        ) c on t.install_path = c.install_path
),
joined_tables as (
    select
        na.*,
        ng.binary_check
    from
        numeric_encoding_groups ng
        join numeric_encondings_all na on na.host_id = ng.host_id
        and na.numeric_encoding = ng.numeric_encoding
        and na.patch_version = ng.patch_version
)
select
    *,
    string_agg(it_service, ',') over (
        partition by numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version
    ) as binary_it_services,
    string_agg(it_org_6, ',') over (
        partition by numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version
    ) as shared_gbgfs
from
    joined_tables
```

I guess the key section of all this code is this part:

```
select
    *,
    string_agg(it_service, ',') over (
        partition by numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version
    ) as binary_it_services,
    string_agg(it_org_6, ',') over (
        partition by numeric_encoding,
        host_id,
        patch_version
    ) as shared_gbgfs
from
    joined_tables
```

How to get `DISTINCT` of `it_org_6` without giving away the partition, group by is not a choice for me in this query, because I must output all rows

Comment: The trick used in ORACLE before DISTINCT was available in LISTAGG was to add a LAG() on the desired column in a subquery and a DECODE() in the enclosing one returning NULL when the LAG() and the desired columns are equals: LISTAGG was not taking the NULL into account...  making the effect of a DISTINCT... so if string_agg() of PostgreSQL has the same behavior will NULL, you could try it.

Comment: Can you please indent that code to make it more readable?

Comment: Please minimize your code!

Comment: To avoid the need for nesting many subqueries like this, postgres has something called common table expressions (CTE) which you could use to make this much more readable. This really helps when you have many "steps" to reach the end goal of your query, as you can write them in the order they occur and give them meaningful aliases. I'd highly suggest adapting to write queries in this style for your own sanity in future! There's too much mess here which distracts from your actual problem, and others will not feel inclined to make sense of it for you either if it's presented in this way

Comment: you guys are right, I am changing here to a `cte` style to everyone, hopefully you can help me now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already doing a `GROUP BY` on the relevant partitioning columns in your first CTE. Just put the `string_agg(DISTINCT …)` there, then you can select the `shared_gbgfs` from that relation:

```
with groups as (
    select
        install_path,
        host_id,
        patch_version,
        (CASE WHEN count(distinct t.it_service) > 1 THEN 'Y') as binary_check,
        string_agg(it_service, ',') as binary_it_services,
        string_agg(DISTINCT it_org_6, ',') as shared_gbgfs
    from
        evergreen t
    group by
        install_path,
        host_id,
        patch_version
)
select
    * 
from
    evergreen t
    join groups using (install_path, host_id, patch_version)
```

<sub>(I've omitted the `numeric_encoding` of the `install_path` as it seemed unnecessary, but you can just `JOIN` it again if you need it)</sub>

Comment: `(CASE WHEN count(distinct t.it_service) > 1 THEN 'Y' END)` will happen after the group by right, effectively not needing the having clause as well ?

Comment: @moth yes, it's quite a simplification :-)